# Backup file using Windows 8 built-in backup tool

Tags: windows-8, backup

I have a 1TB portable HDD and I want to backup my important files from laptop HDD to that.

Question is, if there is any built in application windows 8 provides, to backup selective file/folder with or without version revision?

Comment: Windows 8 does indeed have a basic backup features called `Windows Backup`  There are lots of tutorials on the internet that exist to help you use it.  Windows 8 also supports keeping track of file revisions through `Shadow Copy`

Answer (score 0):

Windows has an acceptable backup application that is bundled with the OS. I had the idea that it's only available in Pro or higher, but I can't find any documentation to back that up (har har). I think this was a limitation in Windows 7 but Backup is now available to all editions of 8.

You can find the backup tool by typing 'file history' at the start screen, then clicking the Settings category.

This blog gives a great high-level walkthrough, including explaining how to include and exclude specific folders: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/did-you-know-windows-8-has-a-built-in-time-machine-backup/

I don't think it's possible to only backup a specific file with this tool.

There are also reams of third party options for backup as well, all with varying features, flexibility, and price.

Answer (score 0):

It may sound quirky, but I actually like [Robocopy](http://www.computerhope.com/robocopy.htm) for this. It's a command line tool that's built into win7's command line. It takes a little command line know how but has some wicked cool options...
Something like this should be pretty basic.

`C:> robocopy /S/ZB C:\Users\username\Documents*.* Z:\backupfolder\` 

but some nicer things are like the /MAX:n that will let you exclude things like say a video library or something that are bigger files so you get your more crucial word docs and stuff.

The /MIR option is particularly cool to me, as it will basically sync existing file trees. The upside to using Robocopy over the build in Windows backup is to me it's a lot easier to cruise through files. Just create a little .cmd script then schedule it in the "Task Scheduler"